# how to use random theme in the beamer class

Tags: beamer

I think it is very cool , push  your favorite theme in a list , and use a random theme when your compile the file. 
is there a simple solution here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a simple way.  Note that it's probably best to vary themes of the same general layout.  This document will change themes approximately every time you compile it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetseed{\the\pdf@elapsedtime} % remove this if using XeTeX
\makeatother
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{theme}{{EastLansing}{CambridgeUS}{AnnArbor}{Rochester}{Pittsburgh}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\Theme}{theme}
\usetheme{\Theme}
\author{I. M. Stochastic}
\title{Changing Beamer Themes}
\institute{Monte Carlo Institute}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```